# I rewrited a class component to a functional one with react hooks, but this is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't rewrite this code into a functional one using the useState and useEffect hooks. The neon cursor should be turned on by the button, but it does not move.

```
function App() {
  const [isCustomCursor, setIsCustomCursor] = React.useState();

  function handleChange() {
    setIsCustomCursor(!isCustomCursor);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChange}/>
        Включить неоновый курсор
      </label>
      {isCustomCursor && <NeonCursor/>}
    </>
  );
}

function NeonCursor() {
  const [top, setTop] = React.useState(0);
  const [left, setLeft] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
      setTop({
        top: event.pageY,
      });
      setLeft({
        left: event.pageX,
      })        
    }

   document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    document.documentElement.classList.add('no-cursor');
      
    return () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-cursor');
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    };
  });
  
 
    return (
      <img
        src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/react/cursor.svg"
        width={30}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: setTop,
          left: setLeft,
          pointerEvents: 'none',
        }}
      />
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

I hope u can solve my problem. I guess the problem is handleMouseMove function

Comment: If the code already works, why are you rewriting it? Don't get me wrong, I haven't written a class component since hooks came out but I wouldn't port one that was working unless there was a very compelling reason.

Comment: @JaredSmith I, on the other hand, *have* rewritten a lot of components simply because function components are more compact and involve less code.

Comment: @Jared Smith I just started learning react and therefore have to do different actions. But the code does not work, the cursor should move after pressing the button, but it does not move

Comment: If you add a `console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY)` in `handleMouseMove`, do you see that output in the developer console?

Comment: @PowerHAHA your question title says "rewrite a class component" implying that you have a working class component that you're trying to change to use hooks. If you have a working version just keep using it. If you don't then please edit the title of your question.

Comment: @Jared Smith initially, there was a class component that I tried to redo into a functional one, but something went wrong. I will edit title, sorry

Comment: @Patrick Roberts yes, but it looks like a random numbers

Comment: The problem is you set the style to `top: setTop, left: setLeft,` when it should have just been `top, left`.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` takes a second argument which should be an empty array in this case. Like

```js
React.useEffect(function handler() {
 // code...
}, []);
```

The empty array means that the hook function runs once when the component is first rendered.

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I got it

```
    function NeonCursor() {
   const [position, setPosition] = React.useState({ top: 0, left: 0 });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
      setPosition({
        top: event.pageY,
        left: event.pageX,
      });
    }
    
   document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    document.documentElement.classList.add('no-cursor');
      
    return () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-cursor');
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    };
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).